# Linux find command doesn't seem to work

Tags: find

Can someone please help me understand why my find command doesn't report the lib64 result like it does with the ls command (note these commands are called in makefile on Debian)

```
LIBXML2  = $(shell find /usr/lib* -name libxml2.so.2.*)
LIBXML2_LS = $(shell ls -1 /usr/lib*/libxml2.so.2.*)
```

Below is the output

```
@echo LIBXML2: "$(LIBXML2)"

LIBXML2: /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2.7.8 /usr/lib32/libxml2.so.2.7.8

@echo LIBXML2_LS: "$(LIBXML2_LS)"

LIBXML2_LS: /usr/lib32/libxml2.so.2.7.8 /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2.7.8 /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2.7.8
```

Comment: Can you try quoting the string after -name?   -name "libxml2.so.2.*"

Comment: No spaces around `=`

Comment: What does `ls -ld /usr/lib64` show?  I'm guessing it's a symbolic link, and so isn't being followed by `find`.

Comment: @Stephen Harris: I think you are right. Unfortunately at the moment I don't have access to the system but I did a quick experiment on a different system (created a symbolic link under /usr to /usr/lib32 folder called it lib44) and the find command didn't list it (/usr/lib44 wasn't listed).

Comment: passing '-H' to the find command resolves the problem

Comment: What shell is that? What's the meaning of using `$(shell ...)`?

Comment: @tomas It's a [makefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile), using GNU make features.

Comment: @waltinator No, this is a makefile, not a shell script. In a makefile, you can have spaces around `=`.

Answer (score 1):

[As identified by Stephen Harris](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302814/linux-find-command-doesnt-seem-to-work#comment531718_302814), `/usr/lib64` is probably a symbolic link on your system. When you call `find /usr/lib64`, `find` traverses `/usr/lib64`, sees that it isn't a directory (it's a symbolic link) and so doesn't recurse any further.

To make `find` look under `/usr/lib64` if it's a symbolic link to a directory, add a slash — putting a slash at the end of the name of a symbolic link to a directory causes it to be interpreted as the target directory rather than the link.

Also put the pattern for `-name` in quotes, otherwise it'll be expanded if there happens to be a matching file in the current directory.

```
LIBXML2  = $(shell find /usr/lib*/ -name 'libxml2.so.2.*')
```

However beware that this is a bad idea. Traversing all of `/usr/lib` is very slow and might find private copies of libraries that you don't want to link against, or unrelated files with a resembling name (e.g. some documentation file `libxml.so.2.txt`).

There's rarely a reason to go looking for a library this way. If the library is in the standard system location, which is where you're looking for it, the linker will find it without you giving any explicit path, just with `-lxml2`. If the library is in a different location, it's typically the job of a `configure` script to look for it. In the case of libxml, the proper way to locate the parts is with [pkg-config](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config):

```
CFLAGS += $$(pkg-config --cflags libxml-2.0)
LDFLAGS += $$(pkg-config --libs libxml-2.0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. My goal was to be able to tell what version of libxml2 was installed on the system and print it out as part of the makefile. One way I figured was to simply print the libxml2 library files and so was doing the above search using find command.

Comment: @Newbie `LIBXML2_VERSION = $(shell pkg-config --modversion libxml-2.0)`